# Why is my background image not showing in IE but working fine in every other browser?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, background-image

IE Version: Latest

CSS & HTML:

```css
#mainbackground {
    background-image: url(../images/mainbackground.jpg);
    width:300px;
    height: 250px;
}
```

```html
  <div id="mainbackground"></div>
```

Things I have tried and that have failed:

1. Having no spaces between declarations.
2. Adding quotes, single & double ticks.
3. Changing height or width to 100%.
4. Checked case sensitivity. Everything is lowercase.
5. Checked visibility & opacity.

Other information:
Works perfect in Firefox, Chrome & Safari.
Animation switches to another background after this one with the exact CSS, just a different ID name and it works fine.

Let me know if you need anything, thanks!

Comment: need the whole css and html and js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First try this:

```
background-image: url('../images/mainbackground.jpg');
```

If It's not works... then there's something wrong with the jpg files, probably. IE8 is not able to render them. Maybe you are using a JPEG2000 format?

Try loading the pictures in an editor, like GIMP or PhotoFiltre and re-saving them (using save as).

You should try to make image files as small as possible on the site because that largely affects the visitors experience.

Comment: The ticks did not work, it was indeed the jpeg itself. It worked fine when I opened it from Windows explorer but when I opened it in Photoshop to play around with the format it wouldn't open and told me the jpeg had been corrupted. Made a new jpeg and it worked fine.